# Gnome panel hides window titlebar

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I moved my laptop screen "below" external screen (was using left/right config before). There's a little problem.

When my gnome panel is on top of laptop screen, all windows I maximize "drawn" under top gnome panel. Therefore, I cannot see window titlebar.

I tried suggested fixes as `metacity --replace` and so on, but none worked.
When I move my taskbar to bottom it works just fine.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Not quiet clear what's going on... you have two screens (laptop and external), you have two panels also or just one panel?

Comment: Just one panel at the top of the laptop screen. External screen is above laptop.

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of the problem?

Comment: Hi cant do that on my own now, because I don't have screen here at weekend, but I googled same problem here: http://executequery.org/temp/images/window-maximized-title-and-status-hidden.png

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work around. In the panel properties set the panel to autohide. This way you should be able to grab the window and move it. Or use the expo effect and move the window that way.

Comment: Thank you, but I really hate autohiding so I don't consider this as solution.